# reading and storing serial port data

Tags: c#, serial-port

**at micro-controller end:**

I am sending 18 bytes from a micro controller via uart to a winform application every 100 ms.

```
UART_SendData((void*)&uart, 18, dataBuffer);
```

**at winform app end:**

I am trying to read these 18 byte. I want to read them in one go, store them and process them as after 100ms new data is arriving (18 is variable and can be 20, 30 and so on till 128 Bytes). Following is the code I am trying.

```
    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        byte[] data = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];
        sp.Read(data, 0, data.Length); 
    }
```

But I am receiving bytes not at a time at winform app end. I receive 1 and then 17. or 2 and then 16 and similar pattern. I want the all data at a time so that I can process it.

What should be my strategy here. Is my current code wrong or should I use any other approach like circular buffer etc to store data?  or ..?

ps: First 2 bytes of the sent bytes (18Bytes in the above example) from microcontroller are always same(kind of an id),

Comment: You could check if the buffer contains at least 128 bytes before reading it out...

Comment: SerialPort read function returns each time at least 1 character is available. You should develope a kind of frame to send your data and check that pattern on receiver side. Or simply count received bytes and exit from receiving when the correct amount of data has been received.